# Initialize hidden form elements

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, jquery-ui

I have a form in a bootstrap popover that is opened with a button.  I want to have "form.date_time_begin" as a datetimepicker but I cant find out how.  If I put the input item anywhere else on the page it works.  But when I move it into the hidden form it will not work.

This is the code in the document ready function:

```
    $('#id_date_time_begin').datetimepicker();
    $('#id_date_time_end').datetimepicker();
```

This is the form:

```
    <div id="popover-content" class="hide">     
    <form role="form">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label>Titill</label><br>
            {{ form.title }}
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label>Lýsing</label>
            {{ form.description }}
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            {{ form.date_time_begin }}
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Vista</button>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

Comment: Where did you get the script for datetimepicker you are using?

Comment: I have the jQuery IU datepicker with timepicker addon from http://trentrichardson.com/examples/timepicker/
As I mentioned, this picker is working everywhere else on the site, including this page I am working on, just not inside the form.
I am guessing it is a problem with initializing the input element.

Answer (score 0):

If I remember correctly, Bootstrap creates a copy of your `div` when you open a popover, so you should initialise the datepicker not on the pageload, but only after opening the popover.

For example:

```
$('#popover-content').on('show.bs.popover', function () {
  $('#id_date_time_begin').datetimepicker();
  $('#id_date_time_end').datetimepicker();
})
```